# If i change picklist value running to completed than my all parent status updated completed

Tags: trigger, class

Question Task 1: Trigger:
1. Create lookup field in contact object of contact, name as "Parent Contact".
2. Create picklist in contact name as Status with below values:
    a. Pending
    b. Running
    c. Completed

3. To do:
   If someone change the status of contact then all parent contact should be updated with the same status.

Example :
    Contact A 
        Contact B
            Contact C
                Contact D

Contact C is parent of Contact D, Contact B is parent of Contact C, Contact A is parent of Contact B

```
Contact A (Status) = Running
Contact B (Status) = Pending
Contact C (Status) = Running
```

And if we change the status of Contact D with "Completed" then all parent should be changed with "Completed" Status.

this is my class

```
public class contactPicklistController{
    public set<Id>ConId=new set<Id>();
    public list<contact>con;
    public contactPicklistController() {
      con=new List<contact>();
    }
    public void workInsert(list<contact> conInslist) {
          for (contact cont : conInslist) {  
                ConId.add(cont.id);
             }
             con=[SELECT id,Parent_Contact__c,Status__c FROM contact WHERE ID IN: ConId];
        }



    public void workUpdate(list<contact> conUplist) {

    }
}
```

this is my trigger

```
trigger statusCheck on Contact (after insert,after update) {
    contactPicklistController obj=new contactPicklistController();
    if(Trigger.isInsert){
        obj.workInsert(Trigger.New);
    }
    else if(Trigger.isUpdate){
         obj.workUpdate(Trigger.New);
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you not using workflows to do achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should go with the workflow approach. 
Use the below code if you want to use a trigger:

```
public class contactPicklistController{
    public static void workInsert(Map<String,String> mapPIdNSt ) {    
          list<contact> ContList = [select id,Parent_Contact__c,Status__c from contact where id in: mapPIdNSt.keySet() ];
          for(contact con : ContList) {
              con.Status__c = mapPIdNSt.get(con.id);
          }
          update ContList;
    }
}



trigger statusCheck on Contact (after insert,after update) {
    Map<String,String> mapPIdNSt = new Map<String,String>();
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate){
        for(contact con : Trigger.new){
            if(con.Parent_contact__c != null){
                mapPIdNSt.put(con.Parent_contact__c,con.Status__c);
            }
        }
    }

    if(mapPIdNSt.size() > 0){
        contactPicklistController.workInsert(mapPIdNSt);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Error: Compile Error: Didn't understand relationship 'Parent_Contacts__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. at line 9 column 29

Comment: please update the inner query and use the object relationship for your child contact : for(Contact con : [select Status__c,(Select Status__c from 'child relationship name' where Status__c != 'Completed') FROM contact WHERE ID IN: parentIds and Status__c != 'Completed']){
            if(con.Parent_Contacts__r.size() == 0){

Comment: child relationship name is Parent_Contact__c it is also present in contact object

Comment: Field label -->Parent Contact


Api Name -->Parent_Contact__c


Data Type--> Lookup(Contact)

Comment: what is the child relationship name goto Contact --> parent_Contact__c--> child relationship name ?

Comment: child relationship name is Contacts

Comment: for(Contact con : [select Status__c,(Select Status__c from Contacts__r where Status__c != 'Completed') FROM contact WHERE ID IN: parentIds and Status__c != 'Completed']){ if(con.Parent_Contacts__r.size() == 0){

Comment: trigger statusCheck on Contact (after insert,after update) {
    Set<string> ParentSet = new set<String>();
    string st;
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate){
        for(contact con : Trigger.new){
            if(con.Parent_contact__c != null){
                ParentSet.add(con.Parent_contact__c);
                st = con.Status__c;
            }
        }
    }
    if(ParentSet.size() > 0)
        contactPicklistController.workInsert(ParentSet,st);
    
}

Answer (score 1):

this is class

```
public class contactPicklistController{
    public static void workInsert(set<string> pSet, string sts) {
          set<String> parentIds = new set<String>();
          list<contact> ConListNew=new list<contact>();
          list<contact> ContList =[select id,Parent_Contact__c,Status__c from contact where id in: pSet];
          for(contact con : ContList) {
              con.Status__c=sts;
              ConListNew.add(con);
          }
          if(ConListNew.size()>0){
              update ConListNew;      
          }
    } 
 }
```

this is trigger

```
trigger statusCheck on Contact (after insert,after update) {
    Set<string> ParentSet = new set<String>();
    string st;
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate){
        for(contact con : Trigger.new){
            if(con.Parent_contact__c != null){
                ParentSet.add(con.Parent_contact__c);
                st = con.Status__c;
            }
        }
    }
    if(ParentSet.size() > 0)
        contactPicklistController.workInsert(ParentSet,st);

}
```